# file_get_content returns empty result on server

Tags: php, localhost, file-get-contents

I am using

```
$url= "https://stackoverflow.com/questions";
$c = file_get_contents($url);
echo "hello".$c .' - '.$url;
```

to echo the content of external page on my page. This works fine on localhost but when I uploaded my page online the `file_get_contents` function returns empty result and my page echos

> hello - https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Try `var_dump($c)` and see if it's returning `false`.

Comment: if it returns false, it may be possible the it is restricted on the server, you can try to set allow_url_fopen =1 in you php.ini, if this still not works, like on some shared hosts, maybe you can try it with curl

Comment: @samlev `var_dump($c)` returns `string(0) ""`

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` only works with a URL rather than a filename if the PHP parameter `allow_url_fopen = On`

This parameter can only be changed in the `php.ini` file or the `httpd.conf` file. See [List of php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)

I assume it is not `On` on your hosted live server. You could ask them to amend the config, but I assume you are on a cheap or free hosting package, so its unlikely as to get any useful features they will want you to upgrade to a chargable hosting package

Comment: I tried adding `php_value allow_url_fopen On` to my htaccess and it didn't work I also added `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);` to my page and it didn't work. Why is this?

Comment: Do I add the `php_flag allow_url_fopen On` line any where in the htaccess file?